# How is "Scope of Work" pluralized: "Scopes of Work" or "Scope of Works"?

Tags: prepositions, grammatical-number, prepositional-objects

If a title of a thing has a prepositional phrase in it, does the plural form pluralize the subject or the object of the preposition, i.e. 'Scope of Work', is the plural form 'Scopes of Work', or 'Scope of Works'?

Edit: Or is it 'Statements of Work', or 'Statement of Works'?

Comment: Are there multiple scopes for a single item os work or multiple scopes for multiple items of work?

Comment: Yes. And also *scopes of works*. It depends on exactly what it is you are making plural. One, the other, or both.

Answer (score 2):

Scope is a collective; it is "Scope of Work;" which can include several items.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't actually answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

"Scope of Work" is a conventional section heading in proposals and contracts.  It is not  an instance noun that gets pluralized like "preface" or "introduction" or "spoon".  A lawyer wouldn't say "I've drafted many Scopes of Work, or should I say Scope of Works, or would that be Scopes of Works...hmmmm".

A lawyer would probably say "... *many a* Scope of Work" if there was a need to refer to more than one of these sections of a document as if the phrase was the *name* of the section or a word for it, not simply a section heading.